# laravel eloquent write new line in varchar

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to add data to a table cell that contains a line break.

```
INSERT INTO someTable (data) VALUES ("111\n222");
```

When I view it in mysql workbench it displays as:
"111
 222"

Doing it with eloquent writes "111\n222" to the table:

```
 $someTable = new SomeTable;
 $someTable->data = implode('\n', $dataArray);
 $someTable->save();
```

I.e. workbench displays "111\n222" instead of the actual new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change single quote to double quotes:

```
 $someTable->data = implode("\n", $dataArray);
```